# Macros vs functions that accept expressions

Tags: macros, julia, metaprogramming

When I try the following code snippet, I got that the variable `i` is not found. Why is that ?

```
function evalMyExpr(expr,n)
  for i in 1:n
    eval(expr)
  end
end

expr1 = Meta.parse("println(\"hello\")")
expr2 = Meta.parse("println(string(i))")

evalMyExpr(expr1,2) # ok
evalMyExpr(expr2,2) # UndefVarError: i not defined
```

Note that if I transform it in a macro it works:

```
macro evalMyExprMacro(expr,n)
  quote
    for i in 1:$n
      $expr
    end
  end
end

@evalMyExprMacro println(string(i)) 2 # ok
```

More in general, which is the difference between a function that accepts expressions as parameters and a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expressions passed to functions are just normal values that are processed at run time. The reason why code fails when it is passed `expr2` is because `eval` evaluates expressions in global scope (in general it is not recommended to use `eval` in functions). Therefore, as probably variable `i` is not defined in global scope in your case, you get an error. See an example when `i` is defined in global scope:

```
julia> i = 1000
1000

julia> function evalMyExpr(expr,n)
         for i in 1:n
           eval(expr)
         end
       end
evalMyExpr (generic function with 1 method)

julia> expr2 = Meta.parse("println(string(i))")
:(println(string(i)))

julia>

julia> evalMyExpr(expr2,2)
1000
1000
```

Now - in marcos expressions are processed in compile time (before the code is run) so the expression you use is injected into the code generated by the macro that is executed afterwards. You can see the effect by using `@macroexpand`:

```
julia> macro evalMyExprMacro(expr,n)
         quote
           for i in 1:$n
             $expr
           end
         end
       end
@evalMyExprMacro (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand @evalMyExprMacro println(string(i)) 2
quote
    #= REPL[23]:3 =#
    for #6#i = 1:2
        #= REPL[23]:4 =#
        (Main.println)((Main.string)(#6#i))
    end
end
```

Observe that the variable name was changed by the macro processing mechanizm to `#6#i` and it matches the name of the variable that is used in the `for` loop.